# How can I make class names unique for my ReactJS components?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am using create-react-app.

### This is the directory structure of my components.

```
/Components
  /C1
    main.jsx
    styles.scss
  /C2
    main.jsx
    styles.scss
  index.jsx
```

### Files

**C1/main.jsx**

```
.. .. .
import './styles.scss'

.. .. . 

render(){
  return(
    <div className='test'>C1</div>
  )
}
```

**C1/styles.scss**

```
.test{
  color: red;
}
```

**C2/main.jsx**

```
.. .. .
import './styles.scss'

.. .. . 

render(){
  return(
    <div className='test'>C2</div>
  )
}
```

**C2/styles.scss**

```
.test{
  color: green;
}
```

**index.jsx**

```
.. .. .
import C1 from './C1/main'
import C2 from './C2/main'

.. .. . 

render(){
  return(
    <>
      <C1 />
      <C2 />
    </>
  )
}
```

**Output**

```
C1 <= This should be red
C2
```

As ReactJS bundles all `.scss` to one `.css` file maybe that's the problem.

How can I make these class names unique by making some change in webpack or code? As you know it's kinda hard to maintain unique class names because we cann't avoid names like `header`, `nav`, `footes` etc to clash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing that is by using CSS Modules

> CSS Modules allows the scoping of CSS by automatically creating a unique classname of the format [filename]_[classname]__[hash].
>
> CSS Modules let you use the same CSS class name in different files without worrying about naming clashes.

### Example from [Create React App guides page](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/):

```css
/*Button.module.css file*/
.error {
  background-color: red;
}

/*another-stylesheet.css file*/
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // reference as a js object
    return <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>;
  }
}
```

Then the button in the example resolves to something like this

```js
<!-- This button has red background but not red text -->
<button class="Button_error_ax7yz">Error Button</button>
```

Comment: Related: CSS [BEM naming convention](http://getbem.com/naming/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are importing scss files in the root of react application. Instead, you can import files only on the component that you want the classes to apply.

> example:  c2 main.js must import scss only under c2

This might solve your problem

Comment: No it's not wokring, check [his](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58893649/8273956) answer. It's working